# Windows 8 Machine reboots when deploying to Windows Azure emulator

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently developing with the Azure SDK on Windows 8.

I have installed the Azure SDK for VS2010 and VS2012 and have both of them on the machine. Unfortunately, whenever I click to debug my Azure web and worker roles on my local machine the storage and compute emulators boot up and then promptly cause my machine to reboot itself.

This happens in both versions of Visual Studio and I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. Any help would be much appreciated.

I do receive the following output though - I haven't changed anything since it last worked:

> Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Certificate identification setting 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption' for role 'VizageAPIWorker' specified in the service configuration file is not declared in the service definition file in the Certificate or as part of an SSL endpont

**UPDATE:**
A blank project compiles and runs with no errors whatsoever

**UPDATE**
Same project on a Windows 7 PC also causes this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really sorry about that, I've fixed this with the latest version of the nuget package:
New Relic x64 for Windows Azure 1.0.0.27 - http://nuget.org/packages/NewRelicWindowsAzure

I am working on a way to avoid having to reboot at all (rebooting could add roughly 4 minutes to new deploys).  The main issue is that the default configuration for an Azure cloud server marks the service "W3CSVC" as manual so issuing an iisreset alone will stop IIS completely - I'd like to replace the call with NET START as detailed here: https://github.com/newrelic/nuget-azure-cloud-services/issues/7

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this problem even when you don't have any SSL endpoint configured in your application, is that your problem? Also if your problem is related with above error, creating a very simple "helloworld" web or worker role, should not cause this problem.

Now if you don't have any SSL endpoint in your application and still see the error:

- Then this problem is just machine specific and could caused by specific setting in your machine.

  - Sometimes rebooting machine, re-installing/modifying application etc just let this problem go away...
  - Try running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to log, file & registry access to see what was being accessed when the crash occurred.

After above test, if your application SSL endpoint specific configuration cause your application and machine to recycle, then it sure could be an issue related to how networking and security components are configured in your machine or exhibit any problem. This could be very specific to your machine and removing factors one by one could help you resolve your problem. This problem is more specific to Windows Azure components in your machine and your machine configuration. You might hit jackpot by finding it soon or may spend countless hours to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks. I have just tried to compile and run a blank project and it worked as it should. I also tried Process Monitor but there was so much data I didn't even begin to know where to look.

Comment: So now I'm going to have to investigate why the SSL endpoint is causing the crash

Comment: Sorry to comment again, but this also now happens on a Windows 7 PC also

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Solved.**

It's a strange one and I'm still not sure if I am at fault. But here's a brief explanation, my instance has the New Relic Windows Azure NUGET package installed on it for monitoring purposes. Unfortunately it seems when you deploy this to the azure emulator it triggers a restart of your machine. I noticed this after delving down into the System Event logs and finding the following:

"The process C:\Windows\system32\shutdown.exe (????-PC) has initiated the restart of computer ?????-PC on behalf of user ????-PC\????? for the following reason: No title for this reason could be found
 Reason Code: 0x800000ff
 Shutdown Type: restart
 Comment: Reboot after installing the New Relic .NET Agent"

Removing the New Relic Agent NUGET package stop the reboot from occurring. I am still waiting to hear back from someone at New Relic to see if it's just me being stupid or a genuine bug.

Comment: Great to know that is was a 3rd party component which was causing the problem. As i guessed it was machine specific issues hopefully you could get some help from them.

Comment: Thank you James! I just encountered the exact same issue and I didn't have a clue about what was causing it. But the reason was the New Relic Agent like it was in your case. Thanks again!

Comment: The startup.cmd file that New Relic uses has the reboot command in it. It checks for the NEWRELIC_HOME environment variable (and if that's set, doesn't do anything) so if you define that on your computer, it should stop trying to install every time you run your site.